# Best C++ Math Library for Game Engine?

Tags: c++, mathematics

I'm looking for a fast opensource C++ math-library for my game engine
with the following features:

- fast (sse?)
- vectors
- matrices
- quaternions

suitable for both opengl and directx

Comment: I don't see why a maths library would be dependent on a graphics API anyway. :P

Comment: afaik opengl uses column major matrices and directx row major. so it would be nice if the library supported both

Comment: In GL, you can always set the transposed matrix, and in DX, you can specify the layout in the shaders. Manually adjusting is also no big deal.

Comment: Platform is important here, because it's quite easy to make a mathematics library that works great on a PC but awful on a console, or vice versa.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

XNA Math might be for you. It's a header only C++ math library that is distributed with the latest DirectX SDK and uses SSE intrinsics. I can't talk much about its performance but from what I read about it, it seems to be pretty decent.

[XNA Math Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee415574%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[XNA Math programming guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee415571%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[DX SDK download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=3021d52b-514e-41d3-ad02-438a3ba730ba)

EDIT: I'm also not sure about the licensing terms. The DX SDK Eula states that "Distributable Code" may not be

> "run on a platform other than the Windows, Xbox and Windows Mobile platforms;"

I'm not entirely sure whether this applies for xna math as only sample and utility code is explicitly marked as "Distributable Code"

Comment: I have no idea whatsoever about XNA's licensing terms, e.g, is it ok to use them in non-microsoft operating systems, for instance. That said, I've used d3dx math library (which is pretty much the same thing) in a software rendering project at one point, so it's not dependent on directx in any means.

Comment: Clarification: d3dx math is probably pretty much the same thing in licensing terms - implementation-wise it's different though. According to SDK documentation d3dx math relies heavily on inlining and pass by pointer whereas xnamath relies on SIMD and intrinsics.

Answer (score 15):

We use [OpenGL Mathematics](http://glm.g-truc.net/)

Even though the name implies it's just for OpenGL I see no reason it wouldn't work for DirectX. It's a header only library, easy to use and is very actively updated.

Check it out.

Comment: uses MIT license

Answer (score 5):

Try [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) -- fast, expression templates, vectorized, easy to use, and is licensed under the [MPL2](http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe CML http://www.cmldev.net/

Comment: Boost software license.

Answer (score 1):

[Sony's vectormath library, used as part of Bullet Physics](http://code.google.com/p/bullet/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fvectormath), meets all your requirements. Some work is involved to separate it from Bullet, but nothing serious - it doesn't depend on bullet, just that no one ever packaged it officially apart from it.

The version currently in the bullet tree supports SSE optimizations, and has a C++ interface.

[An older version (probably now unsupported) also supports SOA formats, and a pure C interface.](http://bullet.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/bullet/trunk/Extras/vectormathlibrary/include/vectormath/)

Comment: Seems like zlib/libpng license.

Comment: I'm interested in this.  You mentioned that some work is involved in separation, do you have any links or other information about what kind of work that entails?

Answer (score 0):

Or, for speed, http://sourceforge.net/projects/simdx86/.

Comment: LGPL, so it's pretty useless. A math library is meant to be inlined, so this pretty much forces your project to be (L)GPL too.