# Is * calling *= (or *= calling *) slower than writing seperate functions (for math library)?

Tags: c++, mathematics, performance, refactoring

I have some vector classes where the arithmetic functions looks like this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto operator*(const Vector3<T>& lhs, const Vector3<U>& rhs)
{
    return Vector3<decltype(lhs.x*rhs.x)>(
        lhs.x + rhs.x,
        lhs.y + rhs.y,
        lhs.z + rhs.z
        );
}

template<typename T, typename U>
Vector3<T>& operator*=(Vector3<T>& lhs, const Vector3<U>& rhs)
{
    lhs.x *= rhs.x;
    lhs.y *= rhs.y;
    lhs.z *= rhs.z;

    return lhs;
}
```

I want to do a bit of cleanup to remove duplicated code. Basically, I want to convert all the `operator*` functions to call `operator*=` functions like this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto operator*(const Vector3<T>& lhs, const Vector3<U>& rhs)
{
    Vector3<decltype(lhs.x*rhs.x)> result = lhs;
    result *= rhs;
    return result;
}
```

But I'm concerned as to whether it will incur any additional overhead from the extra function call.

Is it a good idea? Bad idea?

Comment: This might be different from compiler to compiler. Have you tried it yourself? Write a minimalistic program using that operation. Then compare the resulting assembly code.

Comment: Uh, I don't know a lot of C/C++ but... it looks like `*` and `*=` are doing two different things - the former adds the individual values, the latter multiplying them.  They also appear to have different type signatures.

Comment: This seems like a pure C++ programming question with nothing specific to game development. Perhaps it should be migrated to [so]?

Comment: If you're worried about performance, you should look at SIMD instructions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions

Comment: Why not code both and profile them? It's the only way to know for sure.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: The code is very modern C++. The `+` is an obvious mistake (but the same pattern applies to  `operator +=`). The signatures are different because the syntax is `a*=b` versus `a = b*c` (where `a*=b` is the more efficient form of `a=a*b`). Since they're so obviously related, it makes sense to define one in terms of the other. On the other hand, it's a don't care since modern compilers generate the same code regardless.

Comment: Please don't write your own math library for at least two reasons. First, you're probably not an expert in SSE intrinsics, so it won't be fast. Second, it's much more efficient to use GPU for the sake of algebraic computations because it's made just for that. Take a look into "Related" section to the right: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9924/best-c-math-library-for-game-engine

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In practice, **no additional overhead will be incurred**.  In C++, small functions are usually inlined by the compiler as an optimization, so the resulting assembly will have all the operations at the callsite— the functions won't call each other, since the functions won't exist in the final code, only the mathematical operations.

Depending on the compiler, you may see one of these functions calling the other with no or low optimization (as with debug builds).  At higher optimizations level though (release builds), they'll be optimized down to just the math.

If you'd still like to be pedantic about it (say you're creating a library), adding the `inline` keyword to `operator*()` (and similar wrapper functions) may hint your compiler to perform the inline, or using compiler-specific flags/syntax like: `-finline-small-functions`, `-finline-functions`, `-findirect-inlining`, `__attribute__((always_inline))` *(credit to @Stephane Hockenhull's helpful info in the comments)*.  Personally, I tend to follow what the framework/libs I'm using do— if I'm using GLKit's math library, I'll just use the `GLK_INLINE` macro that it provides too.

---

Double-checking using Clang *(Xcode 7.2's Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 / clang-700.1.81)*, the following `main()` function (in combination with your functions and a naive `Vector3<T>` implementation):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Vector3<int> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
    Vector3<int> b;
    scanf("%d", &b.x);
    scanf("%d", &b.y);
    scanf("%d", &b.z);

    Vector3<int> c = a * b;

    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", c.x, c.y, c.z);

    return 0;
}
```

compiles to this assembly using optimization flag `-O0`:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
Lfunc_begin0:
    .loc    6 30 0                  ## main.cpp:30:0
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $128, %rsp
    leaq    L_.str1(%rip), %rax
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: main:argc <- undef
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: main:argv <- undef
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %edi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    .loc    6 31 15 prologue_end    ## main.cpp:31:15
Ltmp3:
    movl    l__ZZ4mainE1a+8(%rip), %edi
    movl    %edi, -24(%rbp)
    movq    l__ZZ4mainE1a(%rip), %rsi
    movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
    .loc    6 33 2                  ## main.cpp:33:2
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rsi
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    movb    %dil, %cl
    leaq    -48(%rbp), %rdx
    movq    %rsi, %rdi
    movq    %rsi, -88(%rbp)         ## 8-byte Spill
    movq    %rdx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, -96(%rbp)         ## 8-byte Spill
    movb    %cl, %al
    movb    %cl, -97(%rbp)          ## 1-byte Spill
    movq    %rdx, -112(%rbp)        ## 8-byte Spill
    callq   _scanf
    .loc    6 34 17                 ## main.cpp:34:17
    leaq    -44(%rbp), %rsi
    .loc    6 34 2 is_stmt 0        ## main.cpp:34:2
    movq    -88(%rbp), %rdi         ## 8-byte Reload
    movb    -97(%rbp), %cl          ## 1-byte Reload
    movl    %eax, -116(%rbp)        ## 4-byte Spill
    movb    %cl, %al
    callq   _scanf
    .loc    6 35 17 is_stmt 1       ## main.cpp:35:17
    leaq    -40(%rbp), %rsi
    .loc    6 35 2 is_stmt 0        ## main.cpp:35:2
    movq    -88(%rbp), %rdi         ## 8-byte Reload
    movb    -97(%rbp), %cl          ## 1-byte Reload
    movl    %eax, -120(%rbp)        ## 4-byte Spill
    movb    %cl, %al
    callq   _scanf
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rdi
    .loc    6 37 21 is_stmt 1       ## main.cpp:37:21
    movq    -112(%rbp), %rsi        ## 8-byte Reload
    movl    %eax, -124(%rbp)        ## 4-byte Spill
    callq   __ZmlIiiE7Vector3IDTmldtfp_1xdtfp0_1xEERKS0_IT_ERKS0_IT0_E
    movl    %edx, -72(%rbp)
    movq    %rax, -80(%rbp)
    movq    -80(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -64(%rbp)
    movl    -72(%rbp), %edx
    movl    %edx, -56(%rbp)
    .loc    6 39 27                 ## main.cpp:39:27
    movl    -64(%rbp), %esi
    .loc    6 39 32 is_stmt 0       ## main.cpp:39:32
    movl    -60(%rbp), %edx
    .loc    6 39 37                 ## main.cpp:39:37
    movl    -56(%rbp), %ecx
    .loc    6 39 2                  ## main.cpp:39:2
    movq    -96(%rbp), %rdi         ## 8-byte Reload
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   _printf
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    .loc    6 41 5 is_stmt 1        ## main.cpp:41:5
    movl    %eax, -128(%rbp)        ## 4-byte Spill
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    addq    $128, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
Ltmp4:
Lfunc_end0:
    .cfi_endproc
```

In the above, `__ZmlIiiE7Vector3IDTmldtfp_1xdtfp0_1xEERKS0_IT_ERKS0_IT0_E` is your `operator*()` function and ends up `callq`ing another `__…Vector3…` function.  It amounts to quite a lot of assembly.  Compiling with `-O1` is almost the same, still calling out to `__…Vector3…` functions.

However, when we bump it up to `-O2`, the `callq`s to `__…Vector3…` disappear, replaced with a `imull` instruction (the `* a.z` ≈ `* 3`), an `addl` instruction (the `* a.y` ≈ `* 2`), and just using the `b.x` value straight-up (because `* a.x` ≈ `* 1`).

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
Lfunc_begin0:
    .loc    6 30 0                  ## main.cpp:30:0
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    .loc    6 33 2 prologue_end     ## main.cpp:33:2
Ltmp3:
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $24, %rsp
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_offset %rbx, -24
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: main:argc <- EDI
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: main:argv <- RSI
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rbx
    leaq    -24(%rbp), %rsi
Ltmp5:
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: operator*=<int, int>:rhs <- [RSI+0]
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: operator*<int, int>:rhs <- [RSI+0]
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: main:b <- [RSI+0]
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
Ltmp6:
    callq   _scanf
    .loc    6 34 17                 ## main.cpp:34:17
    leaq    -20(%rbp), %rsi
Ltmp7:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    .loc    6 34 2 is_stmt 0        ## main.cpp:34:2
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    callq   _scanf
    .loc    6 35 17 is_stmt 1       ## main.cpp:35:17
    leaq    -16(%rbp), %rsi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    .loc    6 35 2 is_stmt 0        ## main.cpp:35:2
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    callq   _scanf
    .loc    6 22 18 is_stmt 1       ## main.cpp:22:18
Ltmp8:
    movl    -24(%rbp), %esi
    .loc    6 23 18                 ## main.cpp:23:18
    movl    -20(%rbp), %edx
    .loc    6 23 11 is_stmt 0       ## main.cpp:23:11
    addl    %edx, %edx
    .loc    6 24 11 is_stmt 1       ## main.cpp:24:11
    imull   $3, -16(%rbp), %ecx
Ltmp9:
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: main:c [bit_piece offset=64 size=32] <- ECX
    .loc    6 39 2                  ## main.cpp:39:2
    leaq    L_.str1(%rip), %rdi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    callq   _printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    .loc    6 41 5                  ## main.cpp:41:5
    addq    $24, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    retq
Ltmp10:
Lfunc_end0:
    .cfi_endproc
```

For this code, the assembly at `-O2`, `-O3`, `-Os`, & `-Ofast` all look identical.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm going off of memory here, but I recall that they're intended to always be inlined in the design of the language, and only non-inlined in non-optimized builds to aid debugging.  Maybe I'm thinking about a specific compiler I've used in the past.

Comment: @Peter Wikipedia seems to agree with you.  Ugg.  Yeah, I think I'm recalling a specific toolchain.  Post a better answer please?

Comment: @Peter Right.  I guess I was caught up on the templated aspect.  Cheers!

Comment: If you add the **inline** keyword to the template functions compilers are more likely to inline at the first level of optimization (-O1).
In the case of GCC you can also enable inlining at -O0 with **-finline-small-functions** **-finline-functions** **-findirect-inlining** or use the non portable **always_inline** attribute ( `inline void foo (const char) __attribute__((always_inline));` ). If you want vector-heavy things to run at a reasonable speed while still debuggable.

Comment: The reason it's only generated a single multiply instruction is down to the constants you're multiplying by. A multiply by 1 does nothing, and the multiply by 2 is optimized to `addl    %edx, %edx` (i.e. add the value to itself).

Comment: @Adam Aha.  Makes sense.

Comment: @StephaneHockenhull Good to know.  Yeah, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535667/does-it-make-any-sense-to-use-inline-keyword-with-templates) seems to have some more info on the uncertainty of modern-day `inline` and non-specialized templates functions.  Though we all agree that the Q's `operator*()`'s implementation is simple enough that any compiler that's performing any inlining would certainly inline it, right?

Comment: @StephaneHockenhull The inline keyword is a hint which can and will be ignored by most if not all relevant compilers. The only remaining purpose of the inline keyword is that you can write function definitions in header files. In contrast, non-standard attributes like always_inline do have an effect on the inlining behaviour of the compiler.